# xlsx writer set_row sometimes won't work

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I m using xlsx writer to export some files on excel when i try to fix the height of the row with set_row, in case worked in another won't work.

`worksheet.set_row(5, 30)
 worksheet.set_row(6, 30)
 worksheet.set_row(7, 30)`

as a result i got this :

`[image]

we can see that the set_row was applied on the row 7 and 8 and won't apply on the row 6

Can anyone help me with this please, Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The following working example based on your code shows that it works:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('file.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.set_row(5, 30)
worksheet.set_row(6, 30)
worksheet.set_row(7, 30)

for row_num in range(4, 9):
    worksheet.write(row_num, 0, "Text")

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Perhaps you can add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates it not working.

Answer (score 0):

I figured the problem, well you need to use the set_row before writing into the cell.

Comment: That isn't correct. You can adjust the height of the row after you write the data. If you reverse the order of the `set_row()`  and `write()` in my example you will see that you get the same results.